# Allow underscore in PGFPlots tick labels read from table

Tags: pgfplots, symbols, expansion

I'm trying to use the text data from a table column as the tick labels in a plot. The text data contains underscores, which makes LaTeX throw a `Missing $ inserted` error. I'd usually get around this by loading the `underscore` package, and that works fine if I provide the list of tick labels explicitly using `xticklabels={A_B,B_C}`. However, when I use the `xticklabels from table={<table name>}{<column name>}` syntax, the underscores are not printed and I get the `Missing $` error again.

I looked at what the the `xticklabels from table` option does, and basically it just reads the specified table column, writes the content into a list, and then unpacks that list for each tick, using the following macro:

```
\makeatletter
\def\pgfplots@user@ticklabel@list@x{%
    \pgfplotslistselectorempty\ticknum\of\pgfplots@xticklabels\to\tick
    \tick
}
\makeatother
```

`\pgfplots@xticklabels` is the list that the labels were stored into, and `\tick` is just a macro that holds the label text for a single tick. Using `\show\tick` in that macro shows that it really just holds the plain text:

```
> \tick=macro:
->A_B.
```

Now ordinarily, that should just work. If I say `\def\testtext{_}` and then I print that text using another macro, say `\def\printtest{\testtext} \printtest`, the underscore shows up.

How can I use underscores in ticklabels specified using `xticklabels from table` without having to replace the underscores in the data table with `\_`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}


%% For your convenience: This is the unaltered macro that prints
%% the tick label when "xticklabels from table" is used
\makeatletter
\def\pgfplots@user@ticklabel@list@x{%
    \pgfplotslistselectorempty\ticknum\of\pgfplots@xticklabels\to\tick
    \tick
}
\makeatother


\pgfplotstableread{
Label Value_A
A_B 1
B_C 2
}\datatable

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            xtick=data,
            % xticklabels={A_B,B_C}, % <- this works
            xticklabels from table={\datatable}{Label} % <- this doesn't
        ]
     \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex]{\datatable};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In addition to your question, this sounds as if pgfplots should offer more freedom to customize the typesetting of table values. In your case, `$\tick$` would do the job... hm.

Comment: Is the fact that you load your table *before* `\begin{document}` an essential part of the request? After all, the modifications of `underscore` are ineffective before `\begin{document}`, so the table data has "raw" underscore values. If you move `\pgfplotstableread` after `\begin{document}`, everything works well.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger: I tried moving the `\pgfplotstableread` command after `\begin{document}`, but I still get errors with the underscore in the column name. The underscores in the "Label" column work fine though, so that's at least a partial success.

Comment: ah yes... I remember that I eliminated the underscore from the column name. The problem here is of a different nature: pgfplots expects columns names to be expandable material. The active character introduced by `underscore` is not expandable.

Answer (score 6):

Would you consider this as a valid answer? I cannot really test it now and it's too long for a comment. The idea is to "disable the math-mode function of `_` while we read the data".

```
\catcode`\_=12 % category other
\pgfplotstableread{
Label Value
A_B 1
B_C 2
}\datatable
\catcode`\_=8 % category subscript
```

Comment: It's working, but it replaces the underline with a point.

Comment: @Reza: It comes out as an underscore if you use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in the preamble.

Comment: @tohecz: That's a good idea, and I guess it's a nice workaround, but I'd still like to understand why the `underscore` package can't seem to do its magic in this context.

Comment: And when I use lualatex, do I have to specify another catcode?

Comment: @Jake `underscore` changes the catcode of `_` with `\AtBeginDocument`

Answer (score 6):

Here's a patch to the table reading commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
% \usepackage{underscore} % load if explicit underscores have to be used
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\makeatletter
% Patch the command that precedes reading the table
\patchcmd{\pgfplotstablereadpreparecatcodes@}
  {\pgfplotstableinstallignorechars}
  {\catcode`\_=13 \begingroup\lccode`~=`_ 
   \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\textunderscore
   \pgfplotstableinstallignorechars}
  {}{}
% Patch the command that restores the category codes
\patchcmd{\pgfplotstablereadpreparecatcodes}
  {\noexpand}
  {\catcode\string`\noexpand\_=\the\catcode\string`\_ \noexpand}
  {}{}
\makeatother

%% For your convenience: This is the unaltered macro that prints
%% the tick label when "xticklabels from table" is used
\makeatletter
\def\pgfplots@user@ticklabel@list@x{%
    \pgfplotslistselectorempty\ticknum\of\pgfplots@xticklabels\to\tick
    \tick
}
\makeatother

\pgfplotstableread{
Label Value
A_B 1
B_C 2
}\datatable

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            xtick=data,
            %xticklabels={A_B,B_C}, % <- this works with package underscore
            xticklabels from table={\datatable}{Label} % <- this works
        ]
     \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex]{\datatable};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The only way to get a real underscore independently of the output encoding is to make `_` active and equivalent to `\textunderscore`. The example uses `T1`, but runs also with `OT1`.

[image]

Comment: It seems not to work with lualatex.

Comment: @Reza I have no issue if I run the example with `lualatex`, either loading `fontspec` or not.

Comment: It's true, I modified your example, the one you provided indeed worked well with lualatex. In my example I'm loading data from file, this seems not to work.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks, that looks very promising. However, it introduces an error if the column names contain underscores (which works with the unpatched version). I've edited my question to include an example

Comment: @Jake Of course. `:(` For the titles one should stringify them. There's a big deal of catcode juggling there.