# How to read a file with luatex

Tags: luatex, lua

I tried to read a file with lua and set the content as normal text in my document, but I didn't worked it out. Here my code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
  A  B
  1.0 20
  1.1 21
  1.2 22
\end{filecontents}

\begin{luacode}
  function readtxt()
    file = io.open("testdata.dat", "r")
    text = file:read("*all")
    print(text)
    return tex.print(text) 
  end
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
  \directlua{readtxt()}
\end{document}
```

But nothing is printed to the document although lua diplays the content of the file in the terminal.

Comment: That might be related to special characters in `testdata.dat`. The filecontents package seems to add a few lines at the beginning. Have you tried to disable any further interpretation in `tex.print`? This can be achieved by using `tex.print(-2, text)`.

Comment: Yes I tried this, but then it messes up the linebreaks and replaces them with the \Omega letter.

Comment: In your MWE, use a `filecontents*` environment (note the star!) and the result will be good.

Comment: @Reza Would it be correct to assume that you'll want to do further processing on the data here? Will that be in Lua or in TeX (as the line-end business will be important only in the second case).?

Comment: @JosephWright Yes that's correct, I want to pass it to a pgfplotstable, like this I can perhaps circumvent escaping every tex character, like underscore etc...

Comment: @Reza Not directly relevant to the question, but in that case why read with Lua at all?

Comment: @JosephWright We had this issue with underscores in this [thread](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97142/allow-underscore-in-pgfplots-tick-labels-read-from-table)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Edit:** a short version of `readtxt()` function.

```
\begin{luacode*}
  function readtxt()
    file = io.open("testdata.dat", "r")
    tex.print(string.split(file:read("*a"),"\n"))
  end
\end{luacode*}
```

**First proposition:** a solution consists to store lines in a table and to "tex.print" the lines one by one (each argument of `tex.print` is a single line of TeX).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
  A  B
  1.0 20
  1.1 21
  1.2 22
\end{filecontents}

\begin{luacode}
  function readtxt()
    file = io.open("testdata.dat", "r")
    for line in file:lines() do
      print(line)
      tex.print(line)
    end
  end
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
  \directlua{readtxt()}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great solution. IMO even better: `for line in file:lines() do tex.print(line) end` - no need for the extra variable and perfectly clear.

Answer (score 12):

`io.lines` also closes the file and `tex.sprint` writes a new line in the output for every call. The reason why the `%`-lines are ignored by TeX automatically

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{luacode,fancyvrb}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
  A  B
  1.0 20
  1.1 21
  1.2 22
\end{filecontents}

\begin{luacode*}
  function readtxt(filename,suffix)
    suffix = suffix or ""
    for line in io.lines(filename) do tex.sprint(line..suffix) end
  end
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}
\VerbatimInput[frame=single]{testdata.dat}

\directlua{readtxt("testdata.dat")}

\directlua{readtxt("testdata.dat","\string\\par")}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is the right way to implement readtxt for this qn.  Minor tweak: `suffix = suffix or ""` is the idiomatic way to define optional parameters in Lua.

Comment: @CharlesStewart: you are right, I edited the code!

Comment: `tex.sprint` doesn't actually print the new line char in some sense. (in TeX the concept of new line is complex. In this case the `\endlinechar` character is not in the buffer, but the lines are treated as separate buffer lines. Read the TeXbook for details)

Answer (score 11):

The file being written by `filecontents` looks like this:

```
%% LaTeX2e file `testdata.dat'
%% generated by the `filecontents' environment
%% from source `luareadfile' on 2013/02/12.
%%
  A  B
  1.0 20
  1.1 21
  1.2 22
```

When lua reads that in to the string, it does no processing.  If TeX were to read that in, it would ignore the comment lines since everything from a `%` to a newline gets eaten up.  Moreover, TeX would translate the newlines to space characters (and translate any double newlines to `\par` tokens).

The file then gets inserted into the TeX stream via `tex.print`.  This, it would appear, is inserted as if the input parser has already done its job.  So TeX assumes that double newlines have already been replaced by `\par`s and treats a newline character as simply a space token.  However, it still sees the `%` character and is prepared to deal with it by ignoring anything after it up to a newline.  But there are no newlines, so TeX keeps discarding stuff until it is stopped (at the end of the `tex.print`).

I don't know if it is possible to fix this "properly" by getting the new lines to be interpreted correctly, but if you have control over the file contents (as you appear to here) you could get lua to strip out the comments first using a simple pattern match before presenting the data to TeX.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/97822/86}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
  A  B
  1.0 20
  1.1 21
  1.2 22
\end{filecontents}

\begin{luacode}
  function readtxt()
    file = io.open("testdata.dat", "r")
    text = file:read("*all")
    clean = string.gsub(text,'%%[^\string\n]*',"")
    print(clean)
    return tex.print(clean) 
  end
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
Reading in text:
  \directlua{readtxt()}
Finished reading in text.
\end{document}
```

Notice the `\string`!  That's because your lua code is embedded in your document.  It's usually a good idea to avoid that by having the lua code in a separate file.

This produces:

```
Reading in text: A B 1.0 20 1.1 21 1.2 22 Finished reading in text.
```

Answer (score 10):

Another (besides @AndrewStacey's solution) possibility is to use `string.gmatch()` and insert the file line by line:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
  A  B
  1.0 20
  1.1 21
  1.2 22
\end{filecontents}

\begin{luacode*}
  function readtxt()
    file = io.open("testdata.dat", "r")
    text = file:read("*all")
    file:close()
    for x in string.gmatch(text,"[^\n]+") do
        tex.print(x)
    end
  end
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}
  \directlua{readtxt()}
\end{document}
```

And if you want to insert your file verbatim, you can use the -2 catcode table:

```
tex.print(-2,text)
```

Which tells TeX not to interpret the contents of the string.

Comment: I like this one better than mine.