# Read single numbers from data file (LuaLaTeX)

Tags: math-mode, luatex

Is it possible to read a number from data files?

[How to read a file with luatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97822/how-to-read-a-file-with-luatex)

I found the example above but I don't need the whole line at once.

I need somthing like:

```
read(file)
get(A)
get(B)
X=A+B
print(X)
```

Sorry for my bad English. :)

---

Here is my example but it doesnt work :/

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage{filecontents}

 \begin{luacode}
  function addplot()
  filename = "testdata.dat"
  tex.print('\\addplot coordinates {')
  for line in io.lines(filename) do
  local tab = string.explode(line)
  x=tab[1]
  y=math.log10(tab[2])
  tex.print('('..x..','..y..')')
 end
 tex.print('};')
 end
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}

\directlua{addplot()}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Removing the `\\` doesnt work.

Comment: The `readarray` package reads files and allows recall of individual data entries from the file.

Comment: I'm trying to understand exactly what you want.  Then, I would try an answer.  Do you want a file filled with two columns of numbers (A and B), and be able to arbitrarily specify recall of those numbers from a file so they can be added?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\usepackage{filecontents}` should be replaced by `\usepackage{pgfplots}`. `\usepackage{luatextra}` should be replaced by `\usepackage{luacode}`. You should also remove the two backslashes at `{`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{filecontents*}{testdata.dat}
  1.0 20
  1.1 21
  1.2 22
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{luacode*}
  function addplot()
  filename = "testdata.dat"
  tex.print('\\addplot coordinates {')
  for line in io.lines(filename) do
    local tab = string.explode(line)
    x=tab[1]
    y=math.log10(tab[2])
    tex.print('('..x..','..y..')')
 end
 tex.print('};')
 end
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\directlua{addplot()}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the output is:

[image: plot]

Comment: Oh i forgot the pgfplots package -.- thank you very much! :)

Comment: @LukasSchulig If it works for you, you should accept my answer, so that future users know that your problem is solved.