# pgfplots: how to load distinct symbolic ticks/labels from file?

Tags: pgfplots, csv

I want to plot a matrix of color-values from a csv file. Inspired by [this website](http://www.dgsiegel.net/news/2011_12_05-creating_beautiful_graphics_with_pgfplots), I set out to write my MWE below, to which I added [this way](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63335/pgfplots-using-strings-from-data-table-as-x-axis-labels-in-bar-chart) of dynamically loading symbolic ticks/labels from my data file.

However, It turns out that my resulting ticks/labels are not distinct, but instead are repeated, like my rendering shows.
Another way to think of it (according to [@Jake](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2552/jake)'s comments) is that `flexible (x|y)ticklabels from table` does not tell PGFplots that these labels are supposed to be symbolic, as doing it manually using `symbolic (x|y) coords` would.

How can I tell PGFplots that all distinct values from the `xitem` and `yitem` columns in my data file are to be used as symbolic labels?
Maybe the problem lies within `(x|y) expr=\coordindex`. What I want here is to fill in the (symbolic, not numerical) value from the respective colum (`xitem`|`yitem`). But using `x=xitem,y=yitem,` instead gives the error "Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input 'X' as a floating point number".

Rendering:
[image: not distinct]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
yitem,xitem,val
r,X,0.1
r,Y,0.2
r,Z,0.3
d,X,0.4
d,Y,0.5
d,Z,0.6
j,X,0.5
j,Y,0.8
j,Z,0.9
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}\datatable
\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    /pgfplots/flexible xticklabels from table/.code n args={3}{
        \pgfplotstableread[#3]{#1}\coordinate@table
        \pgfplotstablegetcolumn{#2}\of{\coordinate@table}\to\pgfplots@xticklabels
        \let\pgfplots@xticklabel=\pgfplots@user@ticklabel@list@x
    },
    /pgfplots/flexible yticklabels from table/.code n args={3}{
        \pgfplotstableread[#3]{#1}\coordinate@table
        \pgfplotstablegetcolumn{#2}\of{\coordinate@table}\to\pgfplots@yticklabels
        \let\pgfplots@yticklabel=\pgfplots@user@ticklabel@list@y
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    flexible xticklabels from table={data.csv}{xitem}{col sep=comma},
    xtick=data,
    flexible yticklabels from table={data.csv}{yitem}{col sep=comma},
    ytick=data,
    unbounded coords=jump,
]
\addplot[
    mark=square*,
    only marks,
    scatter,
    point meta=explicit,
] table [
    col sep=comma,
    x expr=\coordindex,
    y expr=\coordindex,
    meta expr=\thisrow{val},
] {\datatable};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With the table you currently use, you'll need to use `symbolic x coords={a,b,c}` and `symbolic y coords={X,Y,Z}` (while also removing `x expr=\coordindex,
    y expr=\coordindex`). That's a bit cumbersome to work with, though. There might be better ways to organise your data. How do you generate your data table?

Comment: The table I posed here is just an example; My actual use case contains 25000 rows and 30 columns. I wish there was a way to adapt `flexible (x|y)ticklabels from table` in a way that it filters duplicates. But I don't know how.

Comment: `flexible ticklabels from table` won't help here, because that's just for generating the *labels*, but not the *coordinates*. You're currently plotting the data points at `(i|i)`, where `i` is the coordinate index, so filtering duplicates out of the labels won't help you. Rather, you need to map `a`, `b`, `c`... to `x=1`, `2`, `3`... and `X`, `Y`, `Z` to `y=1`, `2`, `3`... (which is what `symbolic x coords` does).

Comment: If you could create a table that contains proper numerical coordinates instead of the symbolic ones, things would be much easier.

Comment: I can generate numbers/IDs representing `a`,`b`,`c` and `X`,`Y`,`Z`, but eventually I need these original values (not the IDs) to be written near the axes.

Comment: It cannot be assumed for both the `yitem` or `xitem` columns that labels are sorted. It *is* important though, that ticklabels end up in order of first appearance. I have updated the question's MWE to reflect that.

Comment: You need to define how to map the letters to Cartesian coordinates. How do you want to specify that the point `(r|X)` should be plotted below and left of the point `(d|Y)`? I think it would be good if you could update your question to explain in a bit more detail what kind of data we're dealing with here.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please see my remarks regarding `(x|y) expr=\coordindex` and `symbolic (x|y) coords`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12480/discussion-between-jake-and-derabbink)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to generate the mapping from the symbolic coordinates to Cartesian coordinates. If the Cartesian coordinates correspond to the rank of the first appearance of a symbol in a column, you can use the `etoolbox` package to generate a list that represents the mapping, and then use `symbolic x coords` to pass that mapping to PGFPlots:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
yitem,xitem,val
a,X,0.1
a,Y,0.2
a,Z,0.3
b,X,0.4
b,Y,0.5
b,Z,0.6
c,X,0.5
c,Y,0.8
c,Z,0.9
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}\datatable


\begin{document}
\def\xlistmacro{}
\def\xliststring{}
\pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{xitem}\of\datatable\as\entry{%
\xifinlist{\entry}{\xlistmacro}{}{
        \listxadd{\xlistmacro}{\entry}
        \edef\xliststring{\xliststring\entry,}
    }
}

\def\ylistmacro{}
\def\yliststring{}
\pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{yitem}\of\datatable\as\entry{%
\xifinlist{\entry}{\ylistmacro}{}{
        \listxadd{\ylistmacro}{\entry}
        \edef\yliststring{\yliststring\entry,}
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xtick=data,
    ytick=data,
    symbolic x coords/.expand once={\xliststring},
    symbolic y coords/.expand once={\yliststring},
]
\addplot[
    mark=square*,
    only marks,
    scatter,
    point meta=explicit,
] table [
    col sep=comma,
    meta expr=\thisrow{val},
    x=xitem, y=yitem
] {\datatable};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```